# What are all the pokemon pearl ribbons?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I would like to know all the ribbons you can get in pokemon pearl and how to get them.
Currently i have competition ribbons, footprint ribbons, effort ribbons and ribbons from julia. Have i missed any? Do ribbons have any effect on your pokemon, or are they just for display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be omitting the ones that you obtain through Events.

**Sinnoh Champ Ribbon:**

- Obtained by defeating the Sinnoh Champion and entering the Hall of Fame.

  [image]

**Sinnoh Super Contest Ribbons**

- Obtained by winning various contests in Hearthome Super Contest Hall.

  Cool Ribbons (from Normal Rank to Master Rank)

  [image] [image] [image] [image]

  Beauty Ribbons (from Normal Rank to Master Rank)

  [image] [image] [image] [image]

  Cute Ribbons (from Normal Rank to Master Rank)

  [image] [image] [image] [image]

  Smart Ribbons (from Normal Rank to Master Rank)

  [image] [image] [image] [image]

  Tough Ribbons (from Normal Rank to Master Rank)

  [image] [image] [image] [image]

**Battle Tower Ribbons**

- Obtained by defeating the Battle Tower Tycoon.

  Single battles (Ability Ribbons after 20 and 48 consecutive battles respectively)

  [image] [image]

  Double battles (Double Ability Ribbon for completing the challenge)

  [image]

  Multi battles (Multi Ability Ribbon for completing the challenge)

  [image]

  Link Battles (Pair Ability Ribbon for completing the challenge)

  [image]

  WiFi Battles (World Ability Ribbon for completing the challenge)

  [image]

**Memorial Ribbons**

- Obtained from an NPC named Julia in Sunyshore City by visiting her on various days.

  From left to right: Alert, Shock, Downcast, Careless, Relax, Snooze, Smile Ribbons, with Alert Ribbon being obtained on Mondays all through to Smile Ribbon on Sundays.

  [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

**Ribbon Syndicate**

- Obtained by buying one from the Ribbon Society in Resort Area.

  From left to right: Gorgeous, Royal, Gorgeous Ribbons at 10,000 poke, 100,000 poke and 999,999 poke respectively.

  [image] [image] [image]

**Footprint Ribbon**

- Obtained from Dr Footstep on Route 213 when your Pokemon has traveled a lot with you.

  [image]

**Effort Ribbon**

- Obtained from Sunyshore market if your Pokemon has maxed out its EVs.

  [image]